# Apache Httpd.conf settings to avoid cookies for static (image) request

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am working towards having a web application, where the HTTP request for static content (images / JS / CSS etc) is going with the cookies.
Ideally the cookies doesn't hold any significance for the static request except overloading the request.
So, I tried giving the below configuration in the Apache's HTTPD.Conf file:

1. Uncommenting (*It was commented prior to my change*),
        LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so & 
        LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
2. Added below 2 lines,

   SetEnvIf Mime image/.* unset-cookie 
        Header unset Set-Cookie

Post this change, if I intercept the HTTP request using tamper data, I still see the png / jpeg request carrying the cookies with it.

Can somebody help me if I am missing anything else?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted but still change doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The domain name of static image URL should be different than the URL that serve dynamic webpage